# Unable to use Lombok with Java 11

Tags: java, lombok, java-11, intellij-lombok-plugin

We upgraded the Java version from 8 to 11 but I got compile errors of getter/setter methods where I implemented the POJO classes with Lombok's Getter and Setter Annotations.

Is there a way to use Lombok's `@Data` annotation which provides getter and setter without implementing them at Java 11?

Currently, I am facing the error:

> unable to find getStoreName()

where `storeName` was declared as a global variable in the class with @Data Lombok annotation above the class.

Comment: *got compile errors* ... please share the errors as well.

Comment: it says unable to find getStoreName() where storeName was decleared  as a global variable in the class with @Data Lombok annation above the class

Comment: could you update the question with the version details of both intelliJ and the plugin in use?

Comment: Intellij version: 2018.3.2..The Lombok version is v0.10-15.02

Comment: try upgrading the plugin to `v0.22.IDEA-EAP`.

Comment: v0.10-15.02 doesn't look like a Lombok version string to me (and if it is v0.10.0, then that predates Java 11 by about 7 years). Or is it the version of the lombok-intellij-plugin? In that case it predates Java 11 by about 3 years.

Comment: For IntelliJ, just check the Lombok plugin, that should fix it. Lombok support Java 11 perfectly.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**TL;DR**

**Upgrade Lombok as a [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok) and as a IDE plugin ([IntelliJ](https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij), [NetBeans](https://projectlombok.org/setup/netbeans), [Eclipse](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse)) and enable Annotation Processing in IDEs settings.**

---

Latest version of Lombok and/or IntelliJ plugin perfectly supports Java 11.

https://projectlombok.org/changelog

> **v1.18.4 (October 30th, 2018)**
>
> - ...
> - **PLATFORM: Many improvements for lombok's JDK10/11 support.**
> - ...

https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin

> Provides support for lombok annotations to write great Java code with
>   IntelliJ IDEA.
>
> **Last version (0.23) released on 17.12.2018**
>
> ...
>
> - Tested and supports IntelliJ versions: 2016.2, 2016.3, 2017.X, **2018.X**
>
> ...
>
> **Lombok project dependency**
>
> Make sure you have Lombok dependency added
>   to your project. This plugin does not automatically add it for you.
>
> **Please Note: Using newest version of the Lombok dependency is**
>   **recommended, but does not guarantee that all the features introduced**
>   **will be available. See Lombok changelog for more details.**
>
> ...

So please update your lombok/plugin version to the latest ones. Should work like a charm.

Comment: Yes after upgrading the lombok version,it works perfectly !!

Comment: Upgraded lombok maven and intellij plugin to latest version, it worked like a charm! Thank you

Comment: Instructions for Eclipse (2021-09):  To activate Annotation Processing go to Project > Preferences > Java Compiler and check the toggle

Answer (score 3):

For eclipse users you will have to install lombok into eclipse.
Please follow the instruction from here
https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse

Answer (score 0):

As general, update lombok dependency can fix the problem.
Like vsrsion 1.18.4 or latter work fine with JDK11.